# git on windows says untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout but they don't exist

Tags: windows, git

This is a weird one, and I have tried everything both in git and in windows but can't get the message to go away.

I have a folder in my repo as follows:-

```
  /startup
    /client
      /index.js
    /server
      /index.js
```

but for some reason, somehow, at some point, git has appeared to have decided I have 2 other, very similar files, and won't let me checkout my main branch, it forever complains:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        imports/startup./client/index.js
        imports/startup./server/index.js
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I don't have any such named files (and don't believe I ever did), and the situation is totally compounded by the fact that a trailing "." on a folder name is not something windows plays ball with! If I try to rename my startup folder from "startup" to "startup." it just ignores the change.

I've git cleaned with every flag / flags known to man, git forced everything that can be forced, I've even deleted the entire repo and recloned.

I've checked my central repo too, in all branches (master, the current develop, and my own current branch that I'm stuck in), and of course the "startup." files aren't listed - just the "startup" folder as expected.

So I'm at a loss, and putting this out to the community in the hope that someone else can help.

Comment: 1. @Andy Can you please share the  .gitignore file . 2. If these files are not useful for you then you can ignore them and do checkout with git checkout -f Your_branch_Name

Comment: Que :- Is there any package.json file available into your source code? May be some other developer written some code which is creating such folder structures.

Comment: Hey @JoginderMalik I've tried ignoring them but no pattern seems to work - with a pattern of **/imports/** the "folllowing untracked working tree files" message disappears but both files are still reported as "error invalid path".  There is nothing trying to create these files/folder - I'm doing git commands on inactive code repo and those files just don't exist